# Delete an entry from boot options

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, multi-boot, bcdedit

I have installed Ubuntu using Wubi.

It works fine, but for some reason I see 2 entries of Ubuntu (which run the exact same OS) on the boot-up of the computer.

it seems that on Windows 8, I need to use a tool called "bcdedit" (using admin permissions), so I tried in the console to type

```
bcdedit
```

and this is what I got about the duplicate entries:

```
Real-mode Boot Sector
---------------------
identifier              {9dd88019-846f-11e1-afba-9ec96921aa26}
device                  partition=D:
path                    \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr
description             Ubuntu

Real-mode Boot Sector
---------------------
identifier              {e0f9b8e5-bfba-11e1-a157-1c6f6525fc11}
device                  partition=D:
path                    \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr
description             Ubuntu
```

makes sense, so I decided to delete the second one, using:

```
bcdedit /deletevalue {e0f9b8e5-bfba-11e1-a157-1c6f6525fc11}
```

but it didn't work. it showed:

```
The element data type specified is not recognized, or does not apply to the
specified entry.
Run "bcdedit /?" for command line assistance.
Element not found.
```

what have I done wrong? I remember that in the past this was much easier, as I could simply edit the boot.ini file. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Try:   bcdedit /delete {e0f9b8e5-bfba-11e1-a157-1c6f6525fc11}

Comment: it worked. such a quick answer. why did you put it as a comment? and what does deletevalue do anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `bcdedit /delete {identifier}`.

`bcdedit /delete`: Deletes an element from a specified entry.

`bcdedit /deletevalue`: Deletes a specified element from a boot entry.

Use `bcdedit /?` for display a list of Bcdedit commands.

Read the [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us//library/cc731662%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) from Microsoft.

Comment: what's "numproc" ? the link doesn't say anything about it. also, you should have written here the answer and not just the explanation...